# I want my bot to send an error message if it doesnt have permissions

Tags: error-handling, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot in discord.py and i have a question.
I want to have a error handler for when the BOT doesn't have permissions and which permissions the bot is missing. This is the error handler i have now, but i don't know how to do it with the bots permissions and which permission he is missing.

```
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    embe=discord.Embed(title="<:redcross:781952086454960138>Error", description="**Please pass in all required arguments!**", color=0x7289da)
    await ctx.send(embed=embe)

  elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    embe=discord.Embed(title="<:redcross:781952086454960138>Error", description="**Insufficient permissions!**", color=0x7289da)
    await ctx.send(embed=embe)
  else:
    raise error
```

So i want the bot to return

```
embe=discord.Embed(title="<:redcross:781952086454960138>Error", description="**I dont have the right permissions to do that! Please give me {missingpermission}!**", color=0x7289da)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `error.missing_perms` and by the way, this error is thrown when the **invoker** doesn't have the permissions not the **bot** itself.

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send(f"Permissions needed {error.missing_perms}")
```

If you want the error to be thrown when the bot doesn't have the permissions you need to use the decorator `commands.bot_has_permissions(**perms)` and in the error handler `commands.BotMissingPermissions`, here's an example:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.bot_has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)


@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"I don't have the required permissions, please enable {error.missing_perms}")
```

Comment: Can i do this? https://hastebin.com/owehacigot.py Or do i need to write that for every command with every perm?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: But if i do that i get this error: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/343944376055103488/785427190787211274/unknown.png

Comment: That's an invoke error, not related to your question. The error is thrown when the bot can't do somehing, e.g: add roles, manage messages... You have to explicitly add those permissions in the decorator, there's no way of getting the permissions needed with that error.\

Comment: Also, remember to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to read through the docs once beforehand. You can find them here: [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=missing%20permission#discord.ext.commands.BotMissingPermissions).

*Generally you can cover many events with the `error` handler in `discord.py`.*

In your case it is a `BotMissingPermissions` error.

**You can handle it with the bot as follows:**

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send(f"Permissions needed {error.missing_perms}")
```

This is just one of many ways to handle this type of error. You can also output a complete list of missing permissions. (`kick`, `ban`, `manage_channel` etc.)